# Microsoft Application Insights does not show custom properties

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to record additional information when an expection occurs in my application. I have the following code.

```
        var aiClient = new TelemetryClient();
        var properties = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "FullDetails", logMessage + Environment.NewLine + GetDetails(ex)}};
        aiClient.TrackException(ex, properties, null);
```

But all I see in the azure portal are the standard ones in the Azure Portal's Exception Properties Blade.

Comment: how long is your full details property?  there is a limit to how long the value can be before it is trimmed (or it might even be dropped if it exceeds the limits?)

Answer (score 2):

You have to click the little '...' at the bottom of the standard properties section.  that takes you to the "full" properties blade, and you should see your properties at the bottom.

Comment: (although i believe right now they are incorrectly displaying as context.custom.dimensions.[N].value, that should be corrected in a deployment later today, iirc)

Comment: Thanks, I tried to click on that before but it didn't seem to be clickable.
I see my custom property and I can see what you are talking about.
context.custom.dimensions.4.value is the name of my property now.
Unfortunately the view is truncate the value and the eclipses on that one doesn't seem expandable.

Comment: i've seen that too, i have no idea why,  but sometimes on some browsers the mouseover only lights up on some tiny portion of the button?  and other times it is completely fine.  i think we should make that button more obvious than just "..."

Comment: Had this issue too, thanks for the pointer. Do you know of any way to view the full value of the property like @jonantoine required? It truncates quite a lot.

Comment: the full details page is truncating the value?  or is the browser truncating the value displayed in the grid?  we're looking at changing how we show custom properties (so they aren't hidden in that secondary blade), and to better handle giant properties.

Comment: http://imgur.com/p1dmoxO this is how it looks in the trace properties blade, note that this wasn't the error I was trying to view the full value of earlier.